# How to not show user signatures in comments?

Tags: 7, comments

In D7, user signatures appear in their comments. It can be very annoying for many, especially when the signature is long or contain big pictures. So I'm wondering how to disable this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is feature in admin panel of Drupal to disable signature option directly. 
Follow the below steps:

1. Go to admin/config/people/accounts (admin > configuration > account
   settings)
2. Uncheck "Enable signatures" checkbox under Personalization section.
3. Once finished, go down to the bottom of the screen and click the
   Save Configuration button.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7 you can achieve it by overriding the comment tpl file

Steps

- Copy comment.tpl from modules\comment and paste in your active theme(sites\all\themes\your_active_theme\templates) inside templates folder.
- Edit the and comment the following code

  ```
  <?php if ($signature): ??>
    <div class="user-signature clearfix"?>
      <?php print $signature ??>
    </div?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```